# python module throws invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I am writing a module. The python code compiles correctly as python im.py and gives the line count correctly.

```
The error thrown when called >>>import im is
File "<stdin>", line 1
    import im
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

def linecount(filename):
    count = 0
    for line in open(filename):
        count +=1
    return count
print(linecount('im.py'))
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `try` is a keyword, so my guess is that you better do not name a package `try`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not import try, that is a python keyword..

OK; You updated your question. Based on it, do:

```
import im

def linecount(filename):
    count = 0
    for line in open(filename):
        count +=1
    return count
print(linecount('im.py'))
```

i.e. do not indent your import statement.

Alternatively, it seems you wrote import im is -> did you mean import im `as` (replacement name here) ?

Comment: Not a method, a keyword.

Comment: I know that it is sometimes annoying (and I used to find it annoying myself). But eventually I found out that clearly classifying things, makes it easier :)

Comment: tobias, true, but as the user does not make use of it in the provided code, I assume that he is not using it / thought try needs to be imported.